# Samba traffic - Connection down

Tags: networking, samba, performance

Very strange behaviour of my home network.
I connected a new pc to network, via Ethernet cable in switch.
There are also other pc connected, same way.
Since I plugged the cable, each time I open a samba shared drive from this pc (from my main computer) internet and LAN connections get extremely slow, really unusable.
If I connect via SSH everything works fine, so I think is a samba problem.
The point is that configuration is exactly the same of the others pc in my home network, which work flawlessly.
Only this particular PC slows down everything.
Samba shares from this machine are mounted on my main pc as

```
//192.168.8.36/WD /media/topesio/WD cifs username=XXX,password=XXX,uid=topesio 0 0
```

exactly as other samba drives which work fast.

Main PC is running Linux Mint 21.2, each other computers (including the slowing one) are Ubuntu Server 22.04.
Each machine has unique ip address setted in my router.

Any idea??

Comment: You've provided almost no specifics; we don't know what Ubuntu product, or release(s) you're talking about, nor what setup you have. It's possible (*though unlikely*) for a misconfigured setup to cause a *switch* to act like an old *slower* hub (arp spoof/attack) which can slow network traffic down, but we have no knowledge of your OS/release or setup, nor what switch you're using (*consumer switches are more prone to this problem than enterprise grade*) etc.  Have you explored network traffic? (*many enterprise grade switches can provide stats on traffic allowing you to find clues etc*)

Comment: Other simple problems can exist too (*are all addresses unique? what addressing method are you using?  (DHCP/static/mixture etc) have you checked for duplicate addresses etc*)

Comment: Sorry for my hurry and incomplete information..
Main PC is running Linux Mint 21.2, each other computers (including the slowing one) are Ubuntu Server 22.04.
Each machine has unique ip address setted in my router.

Comment: The switch is a Tp_Link 10-ports switch, which works well for any other machine connected though it, I just plugged another lan cable into it....